# Django: '<' not supported between instances of 'model_instance' and 'model_instance'

Tags: python, django, django-views, operators, typeerror

I am trying to find the first and highest value in my table for each ID, and if the if-statement is true; add it to my counter.

**Views.py**

```
keep_track = 0

# if the first weight is less than the highest weight, add +1 to the counter keep_track
for fruit in Fruits.objects.all():
    one = Fruits.objects.all().first()
    two = Fruits.objects.all().order_by("-weight").first()

    if one < two:
       keep_track += 1
       print(keep_track )
```

I thought this would be doable, but I do not quite understand why I receive the following error message:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Fruits' and 'Fruits'
```

Any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always trust the error message. in line 
`if one < two:`

 you are comparing two `Fruit` objects which can't be done unless you overload the `<` operator for the `Fruit` class
**BUT**

 I think that you just forgot to call the right attribute as you just want to compare the weight of the fruits. To do that simply swap upper line for
`if one.weight < two.weight:`

 it will work if the `weight` in your model is stated as `IntegerField` or `FloatField` - actually any type that can use `<` operator by default.

Comment: Thanks! You were right, I used the wrong attribute of course. Object.Attribute solved it nicely, thanks! :-)

Comment: Next time try to focus on what the terminal tells you in error message - it will be much faster than stackoverflow in more complex cases where ppl will not be willing to look into your code. The messages are really helpful you can even use them for intentional checking of your code like what error will such action trigger and so on. Keep coding, cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I tried to google it but had a hard time connecting the results to Django. Hopefully that will improve with time. Cheers!